Merge and rename Google Maps Marker Clusterer related tags
We have markerclusterer with 800+ questions.

This JavaScript library creates and manages per-zoom-level clusters for large amounts of markers on a Google Map. It was deprecated by @googlemaps/markerclusterer.

The tag mainly has questions about @google/markerclusterer and @googlemaps/markerclustererplus which are both deprecated.

And we have googlemapsjs-markerclusterer with 5 questions.
The tag has no wiki but was most likely created for the replacement library @googlemaps/markerclusterer.

Can we merge both tags and retag to google-maps-marker-clusterer?

The questions tagged with the old libraries will automatically be rewritten to be about the new library?

What do you mean? These are 3 versions of the same library. They are all "Marker Clusterer" libraries and all for Google Maps. There is also [tag:leaflet.markercluster] for Leaflet, which is a separate thing and which should stay separated. The original Marker Clusterer and the newer Marker Clusterer Plus were both under the same tag.
